# regex to match at least a character or a space

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using following regex to find out to detect atleast one character.

```
/\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,})$/
```

Right now I need to detect space also.

How can I do that?

Comment: Use `/[\w\s]/.test(s)` to check if a string has either a word char or a whitespace char.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect space in Regex by using `\s`. This token will catch any space in the string. In your regex, You can include this token `\s` inside the brackets `[]`.

Your regex has also `a-zA-Z0-9_` to catch any number, uppercase letters, lower case letters, or underscore `_` . All of these can be caught using one single token that is designed to catch such characters which is `\w`. This is optional, but it will help shorten your Regex to make the tokens between brackets only `[\s\w]`.

Your Regex can be:

```
/\b([\s\w]{1,})$/
```